# Show that $X \simeq Y \simeq Z \implies X \simeq Z$ where $\simeq$ denotes a homotopy equivalence.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory

> Show that  $X \simeq Y \simeq Z \implies X \simeq Z$ where $\simeq$ denotes a homotopy equivalence.

As $X \simeq Y$ there exists $f_0:X \to Y$ and $g_0 : Y \to X$ such that $g_0 \circ f_0 \simeq id_X$ and $f_0 \circ g_0 \simeq id_Y$.

Similarly since $Y \simeq Z$ there exists $f_1:Y \to Z$ and $g_1 : Z \to Y$ such that $g_1 \circ f_1 \simeq id_Y$ and $f_1 \circ g_1 \simeq id_Z$.

Define now $a : X \to Z$ as $a:=f_1 \circ f_0$ and $b:Z \to X$ as $b:= g_0 \circ g_1$. I need to show that $$b \circ a \simeq id_X \text{ and } a \circ b \simeq id_Z.$$

What I have is that $$b \circ a = (g_0 \circ g_1) \circ (f_1 \circ f_0) \color{red}{\simeq  g_0 \circ id_Y \circ f_0 \simeq id_X} $$ and $$a \circ b = (f_1 \circ f_0) \circ (g_0 \circ g_1) \color{red}{ \simeq f_1 \circ id_Y \circ g_1 \simeq id_Z}$$

but I'm not sure the compositions colored in red hold?

Comment: That's the essence but you need to prove all steps you're not sure of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the rules for function composition, including associativity and the how the neutral element $id_Y,id_X$ work.

For the first composition you get:
$$
b\circ a = (g_0\circ g_1) \circ (f_1 \circ f_0) = g_0 \circ (g_1 \circ f_1) \circ f_0 = g_0 \circ id_Y \circ f_0 = g_0 \circ f_0 = id_X
$$

The operation $\circ$ is defined to be associative and that $id_Y$ works as the identity.

Comment: I think the problem is rather that the OP does not know why one can compose homotopies with functions.

Comment: Ok, I can't really see that problem from OP question. He should specify what exactly he wants to know...